# AM-GM Inequality Involving Squares and Proof

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove:

$$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)/3 \geq ((a + b + c)/3)^2$$
OR
$$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)/3 \leq ((a + b + c)/3)^2$$

for all $a, b, c \geq 0.$ The problem wants me to find which inequality is correct and then provide a proof for it.

I'm pretty sure the first inequality is correct (I assumed this after substituting random values as $a, b,$ and $c$). I've tried factoring the inequalities and this is what I ended up with:

$$9(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) \geq 3(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2ab + 2ac + 2bc)$$

However, I don't know where to go from here. I'm also meant to be applying the AM-GM theorem to solve this problem but I'm unsure where and how to apply it in this situation. Any help would be extremely appreciated :)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pedestrian:

$a,b,c \ge 0.$

The first inequality is equivalent to (Dr. Graubner):

$a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab+bc +ac$.

AM-GM:

$a^2+b^2 \ge 2ab$; $a^2+c^2 \ge 2ac$; $b^2+c^2\ge 2bc$;

Adding LHS and RHS of these inequalities:

$2(a^2+b^2+c^2) \ge 2(ab+ac+bc),$

and we are done.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got to the equivalent first inequality?

Comment: Alexander: $3(a^2+b^2+c^2) \ge (a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2ac+2bc)$. Subtract the RHS square terms : $2a^+2b^2+2c^2 \ge 2(ab+ac+bc)$OK?

Answer (score 2):

Your first inequality is equivalent to $$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca$$ and this is $$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\geq 0$$ which is true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can use AM-GM here:
$$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}-\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^2=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{cyc}(2a^2-2ab)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{cyc}(a^2+b^2-2ab)\geq\frac{1}{9}\sum_{cyc}(2\sqrt{a^2b^2}-2ab)=\frac{2}{9}\sum_{cyc}(|ab|-ab)\geq0.$$
Also, we can use AM-GM for three variables.

Indeed,
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a^2-ab)=$$
$$=\frac{9}{2}(a+b+c)\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}-\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^2\right)$$ and since by AM-GM $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc\geq0$$ and $$a+b+c\geq0,$$ we are done!

Comment: Is there a simpler way to prove the inequality but still use AM-GM?

Comment: @Alexander B I posted another way, but I think the first was much more easier.